# How to make the multiple blue legends a single one and adjust its position?

Tags: python, matplotlib, legend

I am trying to draw the following example as a test.
[image: Test]

I need to adjust the legend. Instead of multiple (LoS); I need one like the red line Bresenham's and to adjust its position instead of being in the middle of the figure as shown below.
[image]

Python code:

**Main**

```
import lineofsights as los
import LineOfSight as bren
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

drone_height = 60
risk = [x for x in range(50,60)]
elevation = [[0 for x in range(10)] for y in range(20)]

x1, y1 = 0,0
x2, y2 = 1,9
print("result from lineofsights:")
los.lineOfsight(elevation, risk, drone_height, y1, x1, y2, x2)

print("\n\n")

print("result from bresenham")
bren.get_line((x1,y1), (x2,y2), elevation, drone_height, risk)


xx = [x for x in range(len(elevation[0]))]
yy = [y for y in range(len(elevation))]

xx,yy = np.meshgrid(xx,yy)

plt.plot(xx,yy,"sb",markersize=17,label="LoS")

a = len(elevation)-1

plt.plot([y1, y2],[a-x1, a-x2], "-r",label="Bresenham's")

plt.xlabel('X')
plt.ylabel('Y')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC easiest is just to fetch the handles and labels from `gca` (get current axes) and manually truncate them (just get the last two), as well as moving the legend using `bbox_to_anchor`. So replace `plt.legend()` with something like this:

```
handles, labels = plt.gca().get_legend_handles_labels()
plt.legend(handles=handles[-2:], labels=labels[-2:], bbox_to_anchor=(1.35,0.5))

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Many thanks, dear sir. I accepted your answer.